# Wamp, SlimPHP and Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having issues with getting Slim to recognize the following:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Hello";
});

$app->get('/:name', function () {
    echo "Hello";
});

$app->run();
```

It will see the first route just fine, how ever the second one returns a

```
Not Found

The requested URL /image-uploader/gg was not found on this server.
```

Which lead me to believe I didnt have the re-write mod enabled in wamp. So I enabled it and set `AllowOverride` to `All`

I then restarted wamp and visited `localhost/image-uploader/` and I get `Hello`, how ever visiting the second route gives the error above.

Why? My htaccess is as such:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you accessing the first path via `/image-uploader`?

Comment: @castis I go to `localhost/image-uploader/ ` to access my app. So I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: What happens if you just go to `localhost`?

Comment: I get a list of other projects that are sitting in `wamp/www` its only when I click on `image-uploader/` that I get "Hello" @castis

Comment: Ahh, I had a hunch but I was wrong. Someone will most likely be along shortly and be more helpful than I.

Comment: have you enabled to mod rewrite using a2enmod rewrite? (assuming your on linux)

Comment: Im on windows, so I had to edit the appropriate files to make sure that mod rewrite was enabled. Then I restarted wamp.

Comment: Remove `RewriteBase`, you don't need it (unless you're using `Alias` or other *virtual* path directives)

Comment: You also don't need your first `RewriteRule` seeing as `index.php` is a real file

Comment: Not sure why you'd change it from the default rewrite config ~ https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/master/.htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your project is not in root folder but in `image-uploader` folder, your path is not correct.

You can change `RewriteBase` as follow (assuming your htaccess is in `image-uploader` folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /image-uploader/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, it should be working as expected. Actually, i don't know much more about SlimPHP but it looks like it's fine

Comment: +1 Though I'd just remove `RewriteBase`. There are only very few circumstances where it's actually required