# SlimPHP and Routing - am I doing it wrong?

Tags: php, .htaccess, frameworks, routes

So I recently, as in a day or so ago, asked about why my [routes were not working for slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953704/wamp-slimphp-and-htacess)  and according to the answer, I made the appropriate changes, but unless I am doing routing wrong, they are not working.

If we look at the routing file I have set up, which is required in the `index.php` file, we can see:

```
<?php
use \ImageUploader\Controllers as Controller;
/** ---------------------------------------------------------------- **/
// Routes.
//
// Routes are defined here. Nothing should happen in a route other then
// Calling  acontroller based action, such as: indexAction.
/** ---------------------------------------------------------------- **/
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function(){
    Controller\HomeController::showHome();
});

$app->get('/signup', function(){
    Controller\SignupController::showSignupForm();
});

$app->post('/signup/new', function() use ($app){
   var_dump($app->request()->post('username'));
   var_dump($app->request()->post('password'));
});

// Don't touch.
$app->run();
```

That I have a few routes listed. Now I can go to the first one, it displays the contents of the `HomeController::showHome`, but if I try and navigate to `http://localhost/image-upload/signup` I get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /image-upload/signup was not found on this server.
```

Now my project doesn't sit in the root directory, it sits in image-upload, so when I just go localhost/image-upload I see the `/` route execution results.

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /image-upload/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also my `index.php` file looks like:

```
<?php
/** ---------------------------------------------------------------- **/
// This is the core app.
/** ---------------------------------------------------------------- **/
if (!file_exists('bootstrap.php')) {
    throw new \Exception('Where is the bootstrap.php?');
}

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

/** ---------------------------------------------------------------- **/
// Routing.
/** ---------------------------------------------------------------- **/
require_once 'app/routes.php';
```

**Am I doing slim routing wrong or ...**

## Changes Made

Fixed the rewrite base, it was suppose to be /image-upload/. This how ever did not fix any issues. Mod Rewrite is enabled and on.

Some one suggested pre-pending `image-upload/` (or similar) to the core routes of slim. This does not help. in fact it breaks routing.

Comment: Is *mod_rewrite* enabled ? Is *htaccess* executed ? Just in case, did you try prefixing `/image-upload/` to your Slim rules ? Also, `RewriteBase` in htaccess is set to `/image-uploader/`. Is it a typo or should it be `/image-upload/` as you talked about ?

Comment: @JustinIurman Please see revised question including the Changes made, TLDR, fixed `RewriteBase`, prefixing breaks routing and mod-rewrite is on. yes htaccess is execute, I think - as the first route works fine.

Comment: Well it does not mean htaccess is executed, since `/` is the same as `index.php` in most case. Try putting some random garbage in your htaccess and see if you get a 500 error after that

Comment: at `localhost/` I see a list of projects, image-upload being one. When I put random garbage in the htaccess inside of `image-upload/` I see the project disappear fro the list of projects under`localhost/`

Comment: What if you go to `localhost/image-upload/` with garbage htaccess ?

Comment: I get a 404 not found.The requested URL /image-upload/ was not found on this server. @JustinIurman

Comment: How can it be ? Don't you have an `index.php` file in this folder ? Also, with a garbage htaccess, you should get a 500 if it was executed. It means it is ignored

Comment: I do have an index.php, @JustinIurman its in the question above.

Comment: That's what i'm talking about. It's totally weird, such an unexpected behaviour here

Comment: This is also wamp .... @JustinIurman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76675/discussion-between-justin-iurman-and-kyle-adams).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you give this a try?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Same issue. This does nothing.